# Replacing Win8 with Win7, how to wipe disk?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, partitioning

I have a staff member with a Win8 Asus Laptop.

They have decided they want to wipe it clean and install Windows7. There is no data on the computer they want to preserve.

So, I have a new copy of Win7 Home Premium to install on it. I've tried using custom install and selected the partition and everything seems to go fine. However, when it comes to reboot after installation, it hangs at 'starting windows'. Safemode hangs as disk.sys.

I'm leaning towards deleting all the partitions as I think there is some issue with the Win8 partitions.

What is the best way to replace Win8 with Win7 on a clean computer where there isn't any data or settings to worry about? Should I partition or wipe the whole drive? What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: When in doubt, wipe it clean as a whistle, then install.

Comment: @Moses that's what i'm thinking. Whats best way to remove all the partitions with win8 installed?

Comment: When you install Windows 7, you can delete the partitions in the Custom Install section. Click advanced, delete all the existing partitions, then create a new one.

Comment: The best way is to delete all partitions then allow the windows installer create the required partitions.

Comment: @Moses I'm unable to delete any partitions with the Windows7 Custom Install. So I have to find a different way of doing that.

Comment: @David Does it give you any sort of error message or explanation as to why you can't delete them?

Comment: Check for UEFI, check for Secure Boot, check for GPT boot disks.  All these can screw with Windows 7 if not set up, or prepared for, properly. As-is your question is lacking way too much information, and shows a lack of research effort.  Also asking for the "Best" and "Better" ways to do things are considered opinion-based and will often lead to closure of the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

**Step 1: Remove all Partitions + Data**

I used gParted on a bootable usb disk to remove all partitions located on the harddrive:

http://gparted.org/liveusb.php

I had to go into Bios to change the boot order so it would boot from USB first. I then removed all the partitions

**Step 2: Change BIOS Settings**

I had to disable 'Secure Boot' in bios. You may have to do that before Step 1 to access BIOS:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-access-the-bios-on-a-windows-8-computer/

The biggy was a bios setting called 'Launch CSM'. Once I enabled this, windows 7 installation started without any problem.

**Step 3: Install Windows 7**

Stick the CD in and boot the computer up. Boot from CD and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 5):

Double check the secure boot settings in the UEFI\BIOS, that could be half of your problem right there, but never the less if you're having trouble with the Windows7 setup wizard, we should FIRST clean the disk...

Since it sounds like a problem with the local disk, (as Win8 doesn't like being downgraded) go ahead and just wipe the local disk clean if there's nothing on there you want.

**How to clean the disk manually from the command prompt in the Windows Setup Wizard...**

Boot again into the Win7 setup media

[image: Win7-Setup]

From the windows setup CD you can press SHIFT+F10 to get to a
    command prompt

[image: Shift+F10]

From the command prompt...

```
Diskpart
List Disk
Select Disk 0
Clean
Exit
```

[image: DiskPart]

This should completely wipe the local disk. Reboot and give it another shot. You may also want to use the list disk command prior to selecting the disk to verify disk 0 is in fact the disk you want to wipe.

This should solve most of your problems, as it leaves you with a clean disk to partition and format as you like.